# Need help with Sql Server Full Text Search problem

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, full-text-search, user-defined-functions

I have a `Full Text Catalog` on single table, with three fields defined :-

```
TABLE: Animals
Fields: Name, Breed, LatinName.
```

Now, the Catalog *seems* to be working perfectly.

eg.

```
CREATE FUNCTION AnimalSearch
(
    @Name NVARCHAR(200)
) RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT KEY_TBL.[Key] as Name,
        KEY_TBL.RANK as Relevance
    FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Animals, Name, @Name) AS KEY_TBL
)
```

Now, when i run this, i get the following results :-
Name = ma  (no results)
Name = mat (no results)
Name = matt (1 result - correct).

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[AnimalSearch]('ma')
```

Is this the correct way to use this? I've also tried replacing `CONTAINSTABLE` with `FREETEXTTABLE` .. same thing .. no results.

Any ideas, anyone?

#### Edit

I understand that this could be achieved in a stored proc. I'm was hoping to do this as a Table-Valued Function, so i could use this in some Linq2Sql. If it's really unperformant, then please say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's a good idea. Table valued functions do not store statistics, so performance may suffer.

Comment: I agree with Mitch. A Stored Procedure could give you better performances.

Comment: hmm. i was hoping to do a Table-Valued Function because i can then use it in Linq2Sql.